# R : Bad graphic of ordered boxplot according to median

Tags: r, boxplot

Here is what I am trying to do : I have a data.frame (data) of 160 rows with 2 variables (fact (8 groups) and response) and I want to do a boxplot of response ~ fact, ordered in increasing order of the medians.

Code :

```
data <- read.table("box.txt",header=T)

attach(data)

index <- order(tapply(response,fact,median))

ordered <- factor(rep(index,rep(20,8)))

boxplot(response~ordered,notch=T,names=as.character(index),xlab="treatments",ylab="response")
```

but on the graphic the boxes are badly plotted (not in the right order and with "false" Min, Max, etc...).

I'm using RStudio with R 3.0.2 on Windows 7.

Any clue about what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

One reproducible and seemingly correct answer would be :

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(response=10*rnorm(160), fact=factor(rep(1:8), labels=letters[1:8]))
data$fact <- reorder(data$fact, data$response, median)
boxplot(response~fact, data=data, notch=TRUE, xlab="treatments", ylab="response")
```

Names on the ticks of the x axis are correct, without further ado.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it looks 'bad', but the order is wrong because you use `order` instead of `rank` to find the index. For the other issues you probably have to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The reproducible example is as follows, with two boxplots to compare. In my case the plot (possibly) looks bad because of the devil's ears. Regarding the OP's question, I interpret his phrasing as bad referring to the fact that using `order()` instead of `rank()` resulted in other mishap as well (although I wouldn't know why).

```
data <- data.frame(response=rnorm(160), fact=factor(rep(1:8), labels=letters[1:8]))
boxplot(response~fact, data=data, notch=TRUE, xlab="treatments", ylab="response")

data$ordered <- rank(tapply(data$response, data$fact, median))
boxplot(response~ordered, data=data, notch=TRUE, xlab="treatments", ylab="response")
```

Comment: A lot of thanks for the clue but no need to make fun of my clumsy "bad" or "badly", I was meaning I got something different of what I waited for. Not everybody is a native speaker... I'm a R beginner and I found this example in Crawley's "The R book" with "order" to class the boxplot by increasing order of "mean". Then I tried with "median" but the method turned out wrong. Remains the question of putting correct "names" on the ticks of the x axis. Maybe this time "order" will make it? Excuse my bad English, best regards.